# Arc length of astroid

Tags: calculus, integration

> Calculate the length of the astroid $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$

So I will calculate the arc length from 0 to 1 and multiply that quantity by 4.

> $$S = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^{2}}\, dx$$

$S = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1 + (\frac{d}{dx} (1-x^{2/3})^\frac{3}{2})^2}\, dx$

$S = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1 + ((\frac{3}{2})(1-x^{2/3})^{1/2}(-\frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3}))^2}\, dx$

$S = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1 + (1-x^{2/3})(x^{-2/3})}\, dx$

$S = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1 + x^{-2/3} + x^{4/3}}\, dx$

Have I made any mistakes? If not, how should I evaluate this final integral here?

Comment: $x^{\frac23}x^{-\frac23}=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$(1-x^{2/3})(x^{-2/3})=x^{-2/3}-x^{2/3-2/3}=x^{-2/3}-1$$

thus you have

$$S=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^{-2/3}-1}dx=\int_0^1\sqrt{x^{-2/3}}dx=\int_0^1x^{-1/3}dx$$
which you can easily evaluate.

Comment: $x^{-2/3} + 1$ though, right?

Comment: I've added more details